# Can't upload files in WebBrowser control - windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I am developing WP8 Silverlight application (using VS 2012) and I am using a WebBrowser control in a page to display some web content .

The  issue is ,nothing is happening when we tap on file browse control (inside web browser) .

sample url=  http://dcssrv1.oit.uci.edu/~franklin/doc/file_upload.html

It seems like there is a limitation to access file system from web browser control .

1)  Is there any workarround to implement file upload functionality in windows phone web browser control ?

2) Is it possible to support file upload from web browser control  if I retarget to the app to WP8.1 silver light. If so, can i reatget using VS 2012 or I need to buy VS 2013?

Saw few similar questions in SO but couldn't find an answer for the issue.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't upload files from web browser control for security reasons. Altho my knowledge is limited to WP 8.0.

One solution I would suggest is to use native UI to select files and perform upload. Depending on how much control you have over html content you might have to intercept navigation to file_upload.html page and present native file picker UI instead.